# How to change value of nested optionals in OCaml easily?

Tags: data-structures, ocaml, option-type, matching

I have the following data structure of block which can have an inventory which can contain stacks of items:

```
type item = Stone | Sand
type stack = {
  item : item;
  size : int
}
type inventory = {
  inA : stack option;
  inB : stack option;
  out : stack option;
  prc : item option
}
type blockType = Container | Solid 
type block = {
  blockType : blockType;
  pos : vec;
  oriented : vec option;
  netID : int option;
  sysID : int option;
  inv : inventory option;
  isMachine : bool
}
```

I want to write, in theory, a very simple function which simply adds an item to the **out** slot of a blocks inventory.

**Code**

```
  let addItem block = 
  let oldInv = get_some b.inv in
  if is_some oldInv.out
    then
      let oldOut = get_some oldInv.out in
      let newOut = {oldOut with size = oldOut.size+1} in
      let newInv = {oldInv with out = Some newOut} in
      {block with inv = Some newInv}
    else
      let newInv = {oldInv with out = Some {item=Stone; size=1}} in
      {block with inv = Some newInv}
```

I even used these **heler** functions to avoid having multiple nested match blocks

```
let is_some v = 
  match v with
  | None -> false
  | Some _ -> true

let get_some v = 
  match v with
  | None   -> raise (Er "no some")
  | Some s -> s
```

How can I do this in a more elegant way?

Comment: If your question is how you can do this in a more elegant way, then it may be a good question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Message from the future: [binding operators](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/bindingops.html) as of OCaml 4.08.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify your code, you reached for helper functions that work on options. Consider this helper function:

```
let (>>=) o f =
  match o with
  | None -> None
  | Some x -> f x
```

This defines an operator that takes an option on its left hand side. If the option is `None` this operator evaluates to `None` (no change of input). If the option is `Some x` though, the operator applies the function on its right hand side to the `x`. As the operator is already potentially evaluating to an option (None), obviously the function must also do that. This operator lets you easily use, and chain, functions that let None pass unchanged through them or else operate on the contents of an option.

Which leads to:

```
let alter_inv block f =
  { block with inv = block.inv >>= f }

let alter_out block f =
  alter_inv block (fun inv ->
      Some { inv with out = inv.out >>= f })

let add_item block =
  alter_out block (fun out -> Some { out with size = out.size + 1 })

let set_item block item =
  alter_inv block (fun inv ->
      match inv.out with
      | None -> Some { inv with out = Some { item; size = 1 } }
      | Some _ -> Some inv)
```

Given a block without an inventory or without an `out` slot, `add_item block` returns it unchanged. Given a block with an inventory and something in the `out` slot, `add_item block` increments the count.

However, in a comment you say

> In practice that [raising on error on None] shouldnt be a problem because the function only gets called with blocks where this is not the case.

Which is to say, that part of your code is not really dealing with options. Your types don't match reality anymore, and you're given up the safety of the type checker: that part of your code won't raise any errors at runtime, you say, not because the compiler proved it wouldn't via the type system, but because you've thoroughly checked the logic. If you later introduce a bug to that logic, the compiler therefore won't be able to warn you; your only notice will be a surprise runtime error.

Comment: i think defining the (>>=) this way would be a bit more practical ````let (>>=) o f =
  match o with
  | None -> None
  | Some x -> Some (f x)  ````. It adds the some inside the definition of the operator and allows you to remove it from the other functions

Comment: @ghilesZ That definition is often called `map`, and is a little less flexible because it does not let you alter an option from `Some` to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I might write:

```
let addItem block =
    let newstack () = Some { item = Stone; size = 1 } in
    let newinv () =
        Some {
            inA = None; inB = None; out = newstack (); prc = None
        }
    in
    match block.inv with
    | None ->
        { block with inv = newinv () }
    | Some ({ out = None; _ } as inv) ->
        { block with inv = Some { inv with out = newstack () } }
    | Some ({ out = Some stack; _ } as inv) ->
        { block with inv =
            Some { inv with
                out = Some { stack with size = stack.size + 1 }
            }
        }
```

Elegance is subjective. But the point as I see it is to use pattern matching for what it's good for. Your code seems to avoid pattern matching unnecessarily.

FWIW, your code fails if `block.inv` is `None`. (Also you have `b.inv` where you probably want `block.inv`.)

Comment: Thanks thats much better. I know my code would fail if block.inv is None. In practice that shouldnt be a problem because the function only gets called with blocks where this is not the case. But this is no good practice of cause. And yeah i messed the b and block thing up while I copied it over thx

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain please the meaning of the fields of inventory type ? Everything being an option smell bad ... The ideal data structure constrains the representation of valid states only. If I could understand better inA inB ..., I could try to imagine another proposal of data structure that enable only valid states of data. So much optional fields, I don’t feel it

Comment: Simply put the optional is just there to represent an empty slot

Comment: I understood that, is there some meaning behind this empty slot ?   Like never used block, in activity block, ...

Comment: well it just means that there is currently no stack in this slot but there could be one. But i already figuered it out based on all the tipps i got. Thx anyway